# Fragment UI elements are null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I add fragments to my activity programatically in a for loop like this:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i<bl.size(); i++)
    {ft.add(R.id.linearlayout, new BackflowDeviceFragment(), Integer.toString(i));}//for
    ft.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

I then attempt to obtain references to these fragments like so:

```
BackflowDeviceFragment frag = (BackflowDeviceFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(Integer.toString(i));
```

I successfully get a reference, however whenever I try to operate on any of the fragments' UI elements they are found to be null. So I did some debugging and found that the public methods that I created to operate on the UI elements are being called before the onCreateView() method where I set up all the UI stuff.

When is onCreateView() called? How can I successfully work with these UI elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Fragment [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29), onCreateView() :

```
This will be called between onCreate(Bundle) and onActivityCreated(Bundle).
```

so you shouldn't reference your UI Elements before Initializing.

Comment: I just found out about the setArguments(Bundle args) method. I used this to pass the necessary information to my fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I waited about 10 minutes before I gave in and made this question. After reading up on the activity lifecycle I found that if I called these public methods in onResume() instead of onCreate() everything works just fine. I'll leave this question open if somebody has a better solution.

Comment: I think you can do your stuff on your onActivityCreated() callback function of your on Fragment.onResume() is not the best way

Comment: A quick and dirty way to do one-off operations that works for me is to post a runnable to the view you wish to operate. I'll check my fragment code and see what I'm doing in the meantime.

Comment: @Arash Why should I avoid using onResume()?

Comment: @DrS : because according to Lifecycle onResume() would be called more than once and if you do lots of operations in onResume() it would be a performance issue and it performs it's Tasks more than desire.

Comment: @Arash Yeah I just ran into an issue, orientation changes result in the duplication of fragments.